# MediaRecoder and MediaPlayer conflict

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I'm facing with issue when use `MediaRecorder` and `MediaPlayer`. I need to play guide audio and record video simultaneously in my app. It work fine in modern android device. But in some old device (Samsung Galaxy J7 , Android 7), video record by MediaRecorder seem interrupted by `MediaPlayer`. Output video has frame stopped when audio is playing, when audio end video frame become normal.
If `MediaRecorder` doesn't `setAudioSource`, video was recorded as expect. Anyone has idea about this? Thanks.

This is function set up `MediaRecorder`

```
private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
    if (null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    if (mVideoAbsolutePath == null || mVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()) {
        mVideoAbsolutePath = checkAndGetVideoFilePath(activity);
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoAbsolutePath);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(Constants.VIDEO_BIT_RATE);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(Constants.VIDEO_FPS);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    switch (mSensorOrientation) {
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
    }
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
}
```

This is function to play audio file in resource

```
private void playAudio(int audioResourceId, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onPlayComplete) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), audioResourceId);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f); //set volume takes two paramater
    mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onPlayComplete);
}
```